# How to Remove CommunicationException in Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm just trying to display the current status of mysql server by using the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://Localhost:3306";
    String username ="root";
        String password = "trace";
        Connection dbCon = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query ="SHOW GLOBAL STATUS";
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
        stmt = dbCon.prepareStatement(query);
         rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
         System.out.println(rs);
         while(rs.next())
         {
           String Counter = rs.getString(1);
           int val=rs.getInt(2);
           System.out.print("Counter Name : " + Counter);
           System.out.print("---   Value : " + val);
         }
      }
```

But I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: is Localhost valid? try localhost.  Is mysql running?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating connection with your mysql and didn't mentioned database name

```
jdbc:mysql://Localhost:3306
```

it should be defined as

```
jdbc:mysql://Localhost:3306/test
```

it might solve your problem

Comment: No friend, it also shows the same error message.

Comment: have you changed mysql port?

Comment: Check mysql port using the following netstat /a /o | more in cmd.exe